# In vc6.0, using WinAPI to open the program to expand the monitor some problems

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, device

Below is the main code, the problems encountered, and how they were resolved

***.h

```
std::list<DISPLAY_DEVICE> m_vDisplayDevice_list;
std::list<DEVMODE> m_vDevmode_list;
int m_nDisplayScreen;
```

***.cpp

```
std::list<DISPLAY_DEVICE> devices;
std::list<DEVMODE> modes;
int devId = 0;
BOOL ret = false;   // bool ret = false;
bool isPrimary = false;

//list all DisplayDevices (Monitors)
do
{
    DISPLAY_DEVICE displayDevice;
    ZeroMemory(&displayDevice, sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE));
    displayDevice.cb = sizeof(displayDevice);

    ret = EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, devId, &displayDevice, 0);
    if (ret != 0)   // reinterpret_cast
    {
        // 有‘DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP’标志的显示设备
        if ((displayDevice.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP) == DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP)
        {
            devices.push_back(displayDevice);
            isPrimary = ((displayDevice.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_PRIMARY_DEVICE) == DISPLAY_DEVICE_PRIMARY_DEVICE);
        }
    }
    devId++;
} while (ret);
m_vDisplayDevice_list = devices;
std::list<DISPLAY_DEVICE>::iterator it;
for (it = m_vDisplayDevice_list.begin(); it != m_vDisplayDevice_list.end(); it++)
{
    DEVMODE deviceMode;
    deviceMode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
    deviceMode.dmFields = DM_PELSWIDTH |    // dmPelsWidth
        DM_PELSHEIGHT |                     //dmPelsHeight
        DM_BITSPERPEL |
        DM_POSITION |
        DM_DISPLAYFREQUENCY |
        DM_DISPLAYFLAGS;    // | DM_DISPLAYORIENTATION;
    EnumDisplaySettings((const char*)(it->DeviceName), (int)ENUM_REGISTRY_SETTINGS, &deviceMode);
    modes.push_back(deviceMode);
}
m_vDevmode_list = modes;
```

I used this function to open the Windows desktop shortcut:

```
ShellExecute(NULL,
    NULL,
    _T("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\BasePointV - ***.lnk"),
    NULL,
    NULL,
    SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

I have a problem:

```
--------Configuration: Display - Win32 Release--------
Linking...
***.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__EnumDisplayDevicesA@16
Debug/***.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
***.exe - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)

The project I built is MFC AppWinzard(exe);
Environment is:Windows10 VC 6.0
Online solutions include:
    Define WINVER 0x0500
    Add user32.DLL
```

There are many good solutions, but the linking problem is not solved yet!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: Three things (1) the missing external should be `_EnumDisplayDevicesA` or `_EnumDisplayDevicesW` are you including `windows.h` ? and (2) are you linking with `User32.lib` as stated in the Requirements section here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaydevicesa ? and (3) VC6.0 ( released in 1998 ) belongs in the stone age please update as helping you with products that old may be difficult.

Comment: SO is a Q&A not a _discussion_ forum.  Just ask your question. Discussion should be avoided here.  The "_many good solutions_" you speak of are irrelevant if they are not a solution to your problem.  Stick to the point and avoid waffle and redundancy in SO question would be my advice

Comment: I'd consider switching to a modern Visual Studio. Visual Studio 6 is really outdated for today's developments.

Comment: This may be the first time to seek your help here, I misled you, I feel very sorry!  I'll be more strict next time I ask questions.  I hope I can get your recognition through practice.@Clifford

Comment: Thanks for finding the help files for me.  Even when I saw something similar, it took me 3 hours to research and verify.@RichardCritten

Comment: Your advice is very important and helpful to me.  Thank you! 
As far as the vc6.0 update goes, this would be the most meaningful first thing I recommend the company do, assuming my skills are good enough, I'll do it myself.@Jabberwocky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your linkage error concerning `_EnumDisplayDevices` says it all.

My psychic powers suggests that since Visual Studio 6.0 (released in 1998) predates the availability of `EnumDisplayDevices` (Windows 2000), you are trying to pre-declare the API yourself.  You probably predeclared `EnumDisplayDevices` manually yourself.  Something like this:

```
BOOL EnumDisplayDevices(
    LPCSTR           lpDevice,
    DWORD            iDevNum,
    PDISPLAY_DEVICEA lpDisplayDevice,
    DWORD            dwFlags
);
```

There's two problems with this approach.

First, there's no API called `EnumDisplayDevices`.  There is however, two APIs called `EnumDisplayDevicesA` and `EnumDisplayDevicesW`  for both Unicode and ANSI builds.  The Windows SDK will use a macro to map either one to the thing you can to invoke:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define EnumDisplayDevices  EnumDisplayDevicesW
#else
#define EnumDisplayDevices  EnumDisplayDevicesA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

Second, the actual declaration of `EnumDisplayDevicesA` and `EnumDisplayDevicesW` will are declared as `stdcall` calling type, like most Win32 APIs. Your declaration is likely missing this detail.

Hence, you want to declare this:

```
BOOL __stdcall EnumDisplayDevicesW(
    LPCWSTR lpDevice,
    DWORD iDevNum,
    PDISPLAY_DEVICEW lpDisplayDevice,
    DWORD dwFlags);
```

And this:

```
BOOL __stdcall EnumDisplayDevicesA(
    LPCSTR lpDevice,
    DWORD iDevNum,
    PDISPLAY_DEVICEA lpDisplayDevice,
    DWORD dwFlags);
```

If you manually declared `DISPLAY_DEVICE` and `PDISPLAY_DEVICE` yourself, you may also need to fixup your declaration as well.  That's addressed in the sample code below.

Finally, even after you fix this, you still won't have a lib to link with since your version of `user32.lib` doesn't know anything about this API that came later.

You could find a newer version of the Windows SDK that still works with VC 6.0.  But a simpler approach might to `LoadLibrary` the API directly at runtime.  So putting it all together, here's a complete solution in which we'll dynamically load the `EnumDisplayDevicesW` and `EnumDisplayDevicesA` functions at runtime.  Sample invocation as well:

```
#include <windows.h>

// BORROWED THIS FROM THE WINDOWS SDK - uncomment it if you need it
#if 0
typedef struct _DISPLAY_DEVICEA {
    DWORD  cb;
    CHAR   DeviceName[32];
    CHAR   DeviceString[128];
    DWORD  StateFlags;
    CHAR   DeviceID[128];
    CHAR   DeviceKey[128];
} DISPLAY_DEVICEA, *PDISPLAY_DEVICEA, *LPDISPLAY_DEVICEA;
typedef struct _DISPLAY_DEVICEW {
    DWORD  cb;
    WCHAR  DeviceName[32];
    WCHAR  DeviceString[128];
    DWORD  StateFlags;
    WCHAR  DeviceID[128];
    WCHAR  DeviceKey[128];
} DISPLAY_DEVICEW, *PDISPLAY_DEVICEW, *LPDISPLAY_DEVICEW;
#ifdef UNICODE
typedef DISPLAY_DEVICEW DISPLAY_DEVICE;
typedef PDISPLAY_DEVICEW PDISPLAY_DEVICE;
typedef LPDISPLAY_DEVICEW LPDISPLAY_DEVICE;
#else
typedef DISPLAY_DEVICEA DISPLAY_DEVICE;
typedef PDISPLAY_DEVICEA PDISPLAY_DEVICE;
typedef LPDISPLAY_DEVICEA LPDISPLAY_DEVICE;
#endif // UNICODE
#endif // if 0

// Declare the function types for EnumDisplayDevices
typedef BOOL(__stdcall* FN_EDD_W)(LPCWSTR, DWORD, PDISPLAY_DEVICEW, DWORD);
typedef BOOL(__stdcall* FN_EDD_A)(LPCSTR, DWORD, PDISPLAY_DEVICEA, DWORD);


int main()
{
    FN_EDD_W fnEnumDisplayDevicesW;
    FN_EDD_A fnEnumDisplayDevicesA;

    // Dynamically load EnumDisplayDevices

    HMODULE hMod = LoadLibraryW(L"user32.dll");
    fnEnumDisplayDevicesW = (FN_EDD_W)GetProcAddress(hMod, "EnumDisplayDevicesW");
    fnEnumDisplayDevicesA = (FN_EDD_A)GetProcAddress(hMod, "EnumDisplayDevicesA");

    // now invoke the loaded API function
    DISPLAY_DEVICEW device = {};
    device.cb = sizeof(device);
    fnEnumDisplayDevicesW(NULL, 0, &device, 0); // equivalent to EnumDisplayDevicesW
}
```

Comment: Don't trust MSDN version numbers, it was added in Win98 for multimon support: https://web.archive.org/web/20050218133707/http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/gdi/devcons_2303.asp

Comment: @Anders - you are likely correct. I think the question is whether or not Visual Studio 6.0 shipped with a Windows SDK that declared this API.  Something is amuck with the way the OP is declaring the API - as if they rolled their own header file.

Comment: Your method is very useful and helps us a lot through dynamic load verification!  Thank you very much, I hope my reply will not be too late (because I am a novice, your method is worth reference, my skills are limited, please ask my colleagues to help me to verify hahaha)! 
Through your answer, I feel the power of programming, AND I am honored that this issue has your attention. 
Thank you very much.  Your programming skills and good behavior will be my role model@selbie
I hope I can continue to learn from you

Comment: @又是那条吊带裙 - you'll be a lot more powerful if you can convince your engineering team to upgrade to something later than VC 6.0.  That's a 20 year old compiler!

Comment: If you run this on an old PC (WinNT, 16bit CPU) there is still need to use VC6.0.

Comment: It's a challenge, and I'm not afraid to laugh, but VC6 has been around longer than I have.   
I also believed this to be true when I upgraded to vc6.0.   Even though the difficulty and the number of projects may bring me no small impact and doubt, I will firm up my ideas, which is also related to whether I can keep up with the progress of The Times!

Comment: @selbie Mr. I guess what I'm asking now is: what benefits vc6.0 will bring to the team when upgrading VScode, what needs to be prepared, and things like that...   That will be my question on Overflow in a moment   
I look forward to your guidance as long as it doesn't interfere with your rhythm

Comment: @TomTom Yes, I know 'VC6' was used by the predecessors many years ago, and it is a very popular classic.   In some cases, Vc6 is a better choice, which may be one reason why it is still used by so many people.   However~ although I am a team of four, I do not have such strict conditions